# Fortran : Is it possible to overload a procedure in a abstract interface?

Tags: oop, module, fortran

I wrote the following code where an abstract type (`shape_t`) could be extended to a segment, a rectangle or a box. There are two procedures, one to initialize the variable and the other to print the size.
This code gave the expected result. 
A segment, a rectangle or a box could be initialized and the size could be printed.

```
module myModule
    implicit none
    
    type, abstract :: shape_t
    contains
        procedure(abstract_init), deferred :: init
        procedure(abstract_print), deferred :: print_size
    end type shape_t
    
    abstract interface 
        subroutine abstract_init(this,length1,length2,length3)
            import shape_t
            class(shape_t), intent(inout) :: this
            real, intent(in) :: length1,length2,length3
        end subroutine abstract_init

        subroutine abstract_print(this)
            import shape_t
            class(shape_t), intent(in) :: this
        end subroutine abstract_print     
    end interface
    
    type, extends(shape_t) :: line_t
        real :: length
    contains
        procedure :: init => init_line
        procedure :: print_size => print_linesize
    end type line_t
   
     type, extends(shape_t) :: rectangle_t
        real :: length,width
    contains
        procedure :: init => init_rectangle
        procedure :: print_size => print_rectanglesize
    end type rectangle_t
    
    type, extends(shape_t) :: box_t
        real :: length,width,height
    contains
        procedure :: init => init_box
        procedure :: print_size => print_boxsize
    end type box_t
    
contains
    subroutine init_line(this,length1,length2,length3)
        class(line_t), intent(inout) :: this
        real, intent(in) :: length1,length2,length3
        this%length = length1
    end subroutine init_line
       
    subroutine print_linesize(this)
        class(line_t), intent(in) :: this
        print*,'Line size',this%length,'meter'
    end subroutine print_linesize
    
    subroutine init_rectangle(this,length1,length2,length3)
        class(rectangle_t), intent(inout) :: this
        real, intent(in) :: length1,length2,length3
        this%length = length1
        this%width = length2
    end subroutine init_rectangle
       
    subroutine print_rectanglesize(this)
        class(rectangle_t), intent(in) :: this
        print*,'Rectangle area',this%length*this%width,'meter^2'
    end subroutine print_rectanglesize
    
        subroutine init_box(this,length1,length2,length3)
        class(box_t), intent(inout) :: this
        real, intent(in) :: length1,length2,length3
        this%length = length1
        this%width = length2
        this%height = length3
    end subroutine init_box
       
    subroutine print_boxsize(this)
        class(box_t), intent(in) :: this
        print*,'Box volume',this%length*this%width*this%height,'meter^3'
    end subroutine print_boxsize
        
end module myModule

program main

    use myModule
    
    implicit none
    
    class(line_t), allocatable :: segment
    class(rectangle_t), allocatable :: rectangle
    class(box_t), allocatable :: box
    
    allocate(line_t::segment)
    call segment%init(12.0,0.0,0.0)
    call segment%print_size()
    
    allocate(rectangle_t::rectangle)
    call rectangle%init(12.0,5.0,0.0)
    call rectangle%print_size()
    
    allocate(box_t::box)
    call box%init(12.0,5.0,2.0)
    call box%print_size()
    
end program main
```

But as there are no the same number of dimensions between segment, rectangle and box and I do not know how to overload a procedure in a abstract interface, I use 3 real parameters to initialise variables (even for segment and rectangle where only one or two are needed, respectively).
I wonder how is it possible to modify this code, to change in the main program :
`call segment%init(12.0,0.0,0.0)` and `call rectangle%init(12.0,5.0,0.0)` to `call segment%init(12.0)` and `call rectangle%init(12.0,5.0)`
Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `deferred` procedure in the abstract interface needs to have the same interface in all extended classes. This is unfortunate, but Fortran has no easy way to work around this. I think you have two options:

1. In a relatively simple case like this, you could set some of the arguments to `optional`, and then check inside each class implementation that all inputs you need have already been provided, like:

```
        subroutine abstract_init(this,length1,length2,length3)
            import shape_t
            class(shape_t), intent(inout) :: this
            real, intent(in) :: length1
            real, intent(in), optional :: length2,length3
        end subroutine abstract_init
```

2. Otherwise, you can have a `generic` interface to init. In other words, you're going to write more wrappers to the initialization function, that allow for different inputs. This is an example:

```
module myModule
    implicit none

    type, abstract :: shape_t
    contains

        ! Put init in a generic interface
        procedure(abstract_init), deferred, private  :: shared_init
        generic :: init => shared_init

        procedure(abstract_print), deferred :: print_size
    end type shape_t

    abstract interface
        subroutine abstract_init(this,length1,length2,length3)
            import shape_t
            class(shape_t), intent(inout) :: this
            real, intent(in) :: length1,length2,length3
        end subroutine abstract_init

        subroutine abstract_print(this)
            import shape_t
            class(shape_t), intent(in) :: this
        end subroutine abstract_print
    end interface

    type, extends(shape_t) :: line_t
        real :: length
    contains
        procedure :: shared_init => init_line
        procedure :: init_line_1d
        generic   :: init => init_line_1d
        procedure :: print_size => print_linesize
    end type line_t

     type, extends(shape_t) :: rectangle_t
        real :: length,width
    contains
        procedure :: shared_init => init_rectangle
        procedure :: init_rectangle_2d
        generic   :: init => init_rectangle_2d
        procedure :: print_size => print_rectanglesize
    end type rectangle_t

    type, extends(shape_t) :: box_t
        real :: length,width,height
    contains
        procedure :: shared_init => init_box
        procedure :: print_size => print_boxsize
    end type box_t

contains
    subroutine init_line_1d(this,length1)
        class(line_t), intent(inout) :: this
        real, intent(in) :: length1
        this%length = length1
    end subroutine init_line_1d
    subroutine init_line(this,length1,length2,length3)
        class(line_t), intent(inout) :: this
        real, intent(in) :: length1,length2,length3
        call init_line_1d(this,length1)
    end subroutine init_line

    subroutine print_linesize(this)
        class(line_t), intent(in) :: this
        print*,'Line size',this%length,'meter'
    end subroutine print_linesize

    subroutine init_rectangle(this,length1,length2,length3)
        class(rectangle_t), intent(inout) :: this
        real, intent(in) :: length1,length2,length3
        call init_rectangle_2d(this,length1,length2)
    end subroutine init_rectangle
    subroutine init_rectangle_2d(this,length1,length2)
        class(rectangle_t), intent(inout) :: this
        real, intent(in) :: length1,length2
        this%length = length1
        this%width = length2
    end subroutine init_rectangle_2d

    subroutine print_rectanglesize(this)
        class(rectangle_t), intent(in) :: this
        print*,'Rectangle area',this%length*this%width,'meter^2'
    end subroutine print_rectanglesize

        subroutine init_box(this,length1,length2,length3)
        class(box_t), intent(inout) :: this
        real, intent(in) :: length1,length2,length3
        this%length = length1
        this%width = length2
        this%height = length3
    end subroutine init_box

    subroutine print_boxsize(this)
        class(box_t), intent(in) :: this
        print*,'Box volume',this%length*this%width*this%height,'meter^3'
    end subroutine print_boxsize

end module myModule

program main

    use myModule

    implicit none

    class(line_t), allocatable :: segment
    class(rectangle_t), allocatable :: rectangle
    class(box_t), allocatable :: box

    allocate(line_t::segment)
    call segment%init(12.0)
    call segment%print_size()

    allocate(rectangle_t::rectangle)
    call rectangle%init(12.0,5.0)
    call rectangle%print_size()

    allocate(box_t::box)
    call box%init(12.0,5.0,2.0)
    call box%print_size()

end program main
```

In other words, the `deferred` procedure always represents a shared common procedure to all instances. Also keep in mind that you can always use default initializers, like:

```
allocate(segment  ,source=line_t(length=12.0))
allocate(rectangle,source=rectangle_t(length=12.0,width=5.0))
allocate(box      ,source=box_t(length=12.0,width=5.0,depth=2.0))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I known that I could use default initializers but I want to do some checks and other things. For example, distance must be positive, if length < witdh, distances are swapped, ... (in one word : a setter).

Comment: yeah unlike c++, optional input is not so flexible in Fortran

Comment: Having multiple `optional` length arguments is not a viable, scalable approach to higher dimensions; whether Fortran or C++ is the language is irrelevant. What if you need a 4D cube or 40D or 400D? The only scalable solution requiring only one abstract interface is one with an assumed-shape vector `length` argument.

Comment: @FedericoPerini. In my final code, I never use `shared_init`. So can I simplify it or remove it ? I write working codes but I am not sure it is good practise. In the first one, I have shorten the abstract interface : `procedure(abstract_init), nopass, deferred, private  :: shared_init` and the subroutine : `subroutine init_rectangle() ; end subroutine init_rectangle`. And in the second, I removed them.

Comment: Unless you're writing a DLL/library, it's good practice to only keep routines that are actually used in the code. Plus, how can that procedure have the `nopass` attribute if you're using it as a constructor?

Comment: @FedericoPerini. I am going to ask another question because it is long to explain. I hope it won't be closed for out of topic reason.

Comment: @FedericoPerini. This is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/72994633/7462275